# autohotkey activate window twice deactivate it?

Tags: autohotkey

i have this code AutoHotkey Code:

```
#NoTrayIcon
If WinExist("Mozilla Thunderbird")
{
  WinActivate, Mozilla Thunderbird
}
Else
{
  Run "c:/Users/xah/Desktop/Mozilla Thunderbird.lnk"
  WinActivate
}
Return
ExitApp
```

activated by a key. 
but when run twice (sometimes pressed the key twice), it seems to deactivate the window and change mouse position.

how to fix that?

(this is a pain for me because i have auto window focus on. When mouse position changes to another location, that window pops up to front)

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

someone at ahk forum answered it.
http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/post-413075.html#413075

basically, my script is actually running the Else clause everytime.
What i need is to add

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
```

in the beginning, so the title matches if it contains the string.